# I need to map a XML file (no XSD available) with 'groups' and 'fields' where the field NAME is used to map

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, mapping

I need to map a XML file, where all the groups and fields only have a name,

for example.the address name is a field with name "bdr-naam" and IT contains the value I need to map
    
    `<field name="bdr-naam">Kai test</field>`

I am considering creating either a XDS or the XSLT manually, but could use some pointers.

I've tried generating XSD's for it with Altova XML spy, but none of those work, I've been unable to get a working XSD to do the mapping in a tool like mapforce.

```
<someroot>
  <group name="header">
    <field name="bdr-naam">Kai test</field>
    <field name="bdr-adresregel 1">some addres</field>
    <field name="bdr-adresregel 2">more address</field>
    <field name="bdr-adresregel 3"/>
```

I would hope to either get a XSD that 'works' so I can do the mapping in a tool like Mapforce, OR I would like some help manually creating a XSLT

Comment: What do you want to use XSLT for? To map the XML input format of which you have shown two snippets to another XML output format? How exactly does your output format look like, what are the rules to map something like `field name="bdr-adresregel 1"` with a space in the "field" name to some XML (where spaces in element or attribute names are not allowed)?

Comment: Please show us a minimal but complete example of your XML input and desired XML output.